# How to take a screenshot when video playing?

Tags: iphone

How to take screen shot when video playing? I used MPMoviePlayerController for video playing.

Comment: Press Standby- and Home-Button?

Comment: Ya..I want programatically take screen shot when i click the button to take screen shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (UIImage *) captureScreen 
{
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Comment: One more doubt...Movie player is playing video showing but taking screen shot only black background...How to solve this.

Comment: @Dev_Mani: for that refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859430/why-cant-i-capture-a-screenshot-of-mpmovieplayercontroller